# R ggplot2 plotting hourly data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot hourly meteorological data coming from a meteorological station with ggplot2 (it's my first time with ggplot). I've managed to plot daily data but having some problem when downscaling to hourly data. Data files look like that:

```
FECHA H_SOLAR;DIR_M;VEL_M;TEMP_M;HR;PRECIP
01/06/14 00:50:00;314.3;1.9;14.1;68.0;-99.9
01/06/14 01:50:00;322.0;1.6;13.3;68.9;-99.9
01/06/14 02:50:00;303.5;2.1;12.3;70.9;-99.9
01/06/14 03:50:00;302.4;1.6;11.6;73.1;-99.9
01/06/14 04:50:00;306.5;1.2;10.9;76.4;-99.9
01/06/14 05:50:00;317.1;0.8;12.6;71.5;-99.9
01/06/14 06:50:00;341.8;0.0;17.1;58.8;-99.9
01/06/14 07:50:00;264.6;1.2;21.8;44.9;-99.9
01/06/14 08:50:00;253.8;2.9;24.7;32.2;-99.9
01/06/14 09:50:00;254.6;3.7;26.7;27.7;-99.9
01/06/14 10:50:00;250.7;4.3;28.3;24.9;-99.9
01/06/14 11:50:00;248.5;5.3;29.1;22.6;-99.9
01/06/14 12:50:00;242.8;4.7;30.3;20.4;-99.9
01/06/14 13:50:00;260.7;4.9;31.3;17.4;-99.9
01/06/14 14:50:00;251.8;5.1;31.9;17.1;-99.9
01/06/14 15:50:00;258.1;4.6;32.4;15.3;-99.9
01/06/14 16:50:00;254.3;5.7;32.4;14.0;-99.9
01/06/14 17:50:00;252.5;4.6;32.0;14.1;-99.9
01/06/14 18:50:00;257.4;3.8;31.1;14.9;-99.9
01/06/14 19:50:00;135.8;4.2;26.0;41.2;-99.9
01/06/14 20:50:00;126.0;1.7;23.5;48.7;-99.9
01/06/14 21:50:00;302.8;0.7;21.6;53.9;-99.9
01/06/14 22:50:00;294.2;1.1;19.3;67.4;-99.9
01/06/14 23:50:00;308.5;1.0;17.5;72.4;-99.9
```

I have used this R commands to plot the data:

```
datos=read.csv("utiel.dat",sep=";",header=T,na.strings="-99.9")

dia=as.Date(datos[,1],"%y/%m/%d")       # Crear índice dia
veloc=zoo(datos[,c("VEL_M")],dia)       

gveloc=ggplot(data=datos,aes(dia,veloc))

gveloc + geom_point(colour="blue",cex=1) + ylab("Velocidad (km/h)") + xlab("Fecha") + opts(title="Velocidad media horaria") + scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2007-01-01","2007-01-31")),format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

and got this monthly graph with all data from a single day in the same x coordinate (i.e. the same day as it could be expected)

[image: Hourly wind data with ggplot2]

How can I manage to read not only the day but the time so each point can be plotted in it's own x/time coordinate? I think the problem starts before plotting but I couldn't find how to read date as YY/MM/DD H:M:S

Thanks in advance

Solution: Just an addition to put the code has worked for me

```
 datos$dia=as.POSIXct(datos[,1], format="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")  # Read date/time as POSIXct

 ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=dia, y=TEMP_M)) + 
   geom_point(colour="red") + 
   ylab("Temperatura (ºC)") + 
   xlab("Fecha") + 
   opts(title="Temperatura media") + 
   scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct('2008/02/01'), as.POSIXct('2008/02/02')) ,format =  "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Hope it helps someone else, thanks Andrie and G.Grothendieck

Comment: Hi, I can't see your full coment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`as.Date` only capture the date element.  To capture time, you need to use `as.POSIXct`:

Recreate your data:

```
zz <- tempfile()
cat("
FECHA H_SOLAR;DIR_M;VEL_M;TEMP_M;HR;PRECIP
01/06/14 00:50:00;314.3;1.9;14.1;68.0;-99.9
01/06/14 01:50:00;322.0;1.6;13.3;68.9;-99.9
01/06/14 02:50:00;303.5;2.1;12.3;70.9;-99.9
01/06/14 03:50:00;302.4;1.6;11.6;73.1;-99.9
01/06/14 04:50:00;306.5;1.2;10.9;76.4;-99.9
01/06/14 05:50:00;317.1;0.8;12.6;71.5;-99.9
01/06/14 06:50:00;341.8;0.0;17.1;58.8;-99.9
01/06/14 07:50:00;264.6;1.2;21.8;44.9;-99.9
01/06/14 08:50:00;253.8;2.9;24.7;32.2;-99.9
01/06/14 09:50:00;254.6;3.7;26.7;27.7;-99.9
01/06/14 10:50:00;250.7;4.3;28.3;24.9;-99.9
01/06/14 11:50:00;248.5;5.3;29.1;22.6;-99.9
01/06/14 12:50:00;242.8;4.7;30.3;20.4;-99.9
01/06/14 13:50:00;260.7;4.9;31.3;17.4;-99.9
01/06/14 14:50:00;251.8;5.1;31.9;17.1;-99.9
01/06/14 15:50:00;258.1;4.6;32.4;15.3;-99.9
01/06/14 16:50:00;254.3;5.7;32.4;14.0;-99.9
01/06/14 17:50:00;252.5;4.6;32.0;14.1;-99.9
01/06/14 18:50:00;257.4;3.8;31.1;14.9;-99.9
01/06/14 19:50:00;135.8;4.2;26.0;41.2;-99.9
01/06/14 20:50:00;126.0;1.7;23.5;48.7;-99.9
01/06/14 21:50:00;302.8;0.7;21.6;53.9;-99.9
01/06/14 22:50:00;294.2;1.1;19.3;67.4;-99.9
01/06/14 23:50:00;308.5;1.0;17.5;72.4;-99.9
", file=zz)

datos=read.csv(zz, sep=";", header=TRUE, na.strings="-99.9")
```

Convert dates to `POSIXct` and print:

```
library(ggplot2)

datos=read.csv(zz, sep=";", header=TRUE, na.strings="-99.9")

datos$dia=as.POSIXct(datos[,1], format="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")  

ggplot(data=datos,aes(x=dia, y=TEMP_M)) + 
  geom_path(colour="red") + 
  ylab("Temperatura (ºC)") + 
  xlab("Fecha") + 
  opts(title="Temperatura media")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer Andrie, thanks. It works fine with the daily data I posted but the point is that my data spans for ten years. Then I need to set the set_x_scale option to choose the time period I want to plot (day to months). I am not able to reproduce the graph for a month. Is it necessary to recreate the data?

Comment: You'll have to specify your limits to the scale also as `POSIXct` dates, not `as Date`.

Comment: How should I set the limits as POSIXct? Maybe something like: `scale_x_date(limits = as.POSIXct(c("2004-01-01", "2005-01-01")),
  format = "%Y-%m-%d")` ??  Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've finally found how to set the x axis limits as POSIX.ct. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using zoo we can use `read.zoo` to set up the data, `z`, and then plot it using `plot.zoo`, `xyplot.zoo` or ggplot2's `qplot`.  We show all three below.

```
Lines <- "FECHA H_SOLAR;DIR_M;VEL_M;TEMP_M;HR;PRECIP
01/06/14 00:50:00;314.3;1.9;14.1;68.0;-99.9
01/06/14 01:50:00;322.0;1.6;13.3;68.9;-99.9
01/06/14 02:50:00;303.5;2.1;12.3;70.9;-99.9
01/06/14 03:50:00;302.4;1.6;11.6;73.1;-99.9
01/06/14 04:50:00;306.5;1.2;10.9;76.4;-99.9
01/06/14 05:50:00;317.1;0.8;12.6;71.5;-99.9
01/06/14 06:50:00;341.8;0.0;17.1;58.8;-99.9
01/06/14 07:50:00;264.6;1.2;21.8;44.9;-99.9
01/06/14 08:50:00;253.8;2.9;24.7;32.2;-99.9
01/06/14 09:50:00;254.6;3.7;26.7;27.7;-99.9
01/06/14 10:50:00;250.7;4.3;28.3;24.9;-99.9
01/06/14 11:50:00;248.5;5.3;29.1;22.6;-99.9
01/06/14 12:50:00;242.8;4.7;30.3;20.4;-99.9
01/06/14 13:50:00;260.7;4.9;31.3;17.4;-99.9
01/06/14 14:50:00;251.8;5.1;31.9;17.1;-99.9
01/06/14 15:50:00;258.1;4.6;32.4;15.3;-99.9
01/06/14 16:50:00;254.3;5.7;32.4;14.0;-99.9
01/06/14 17:50:00;252.5;4.6;32.0;14.1;-99.9
01/06/14 18:50:00;257.4;3.8;31.1;14.9;-99.9
01/06/14 19:50:00;135.8;4.2;26.0;41.2;-99.9
01/06/14 20:50:00;126.0;1.7;23.5;48.7;-99.9
01/06/14 21:50:00;302.8;0.7;21.6;53.9;-99.9
01/06/14 22:50:00;294.2;1.1;19.3;67.4;-99.9
01/06/14 23:50:00;308.5;1.0;17.5;72.4;-99.9"
cat(Lines, "\n", file = "data.txt")

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo("data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";", na.strings = "-99.9", 
        tz = "", format = "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
# move last 12 points into following day
time(z)[13:24] <- time(z)[13:24] + 24 * 60 * 60
xlim <- as.POSIXct(c("2001-06-14 00:00:00", "2001-06-14 12:00:00"))
```

Here are the 3 ways to plot it:

**1 - classic graphics** using `plot.zoo`:

```
# Create manual axis since classic graphic's default is not so good.
# Axis might be ok for real data in which case manual axis setting can be omitted
plot(z$VEL_M, type = "p", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", col = "blue", xlim = xlim,
    xaxt = "n")
xaxis <- seq(xlim[1], xlim[2], by = "hour")
axis(1, xaxis, as.POSIXlt(xaxis)$hour)
```

**2 - lattice graphics** using `xyplot.zoo` :

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(z$VEL_M, type = "p", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", col = "blue", xlim = xlim)
```

**3 - ggplot2** using `qplot`:

```
# unlike classic graphics and lattice graphics, zoo currently 
# does not have a specific interface but we can do this:
library(ggplot2)
qplot(time(z), z$VEL_M, xlab = "X", ylab = "Y") + 
    geom_point(colour = "blue") +
    scale_x_datetime(limits = xlim)
```

**EDIT:**

Have modified example in order to illustrate limiting the X axis.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I have tried the ggplot2 option and works fine for the whole data set but I can't make the graphic when trying to set x axis limits. I try `scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2007-01-01","2007-01-31")),format = "%Y-%m-%d")` and then no point appears, x limits are well defined but any data. R says that "Removed 105192 rows containing missing values (geom_point)".  Any idea?

Comment: Hi again. I've accepted the other answer as it helped me to understand about POSIXct date and time format buy yours it was also helpful.

Comment: @pacomet.  Have modified example to illustrate limiting X axis.