# Scaling Time in Hours in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following plot I wanted to remove the date and keep the time in hours. I have seen few solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636733/r-ggplot2-ploting-hourly-data) and another where Time is converted to numeric. I liked the use of `require(scales)`

```
ggplot(data= dfweek2, aes(x = Time, y = Mean_steps)) + facet_grid(day ~.) + geom_path()
```

this is my plot 
[image]

When I change to 
`require(scales)
ggplot(data= dfweek2, aes(x = Time, y = Mean_steps)) + facet_grid(day ~.) + geom_path() + scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M"))`

this scale is not longer correct...[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
> str(dfweek2)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 576 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ day       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Weekday","Weekend": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ interval  : int  0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 ...
 $ Mean_steps: num  2.333 0.462 0.179 0.205 0.103 ...
 $ Time      : POSIXct, format: "2015-06-15 00:00:00" "2015-06-15 00:05:00" ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if it's a timezone thing. Look at the output of `attributes(dfweek2$Time)` and see if it has a `tzone` attribute. If it does, then when `format` is called without a `tz` parameter, it will convert the times from whatever time zone they're stored as to whatever system time zone you've got set. If this is the case, you have two options.

1. Remove the tzone attribute from `dfweek2$Time`

   `attr(dfweek2$Time, "tzone") <- NULL`
2. Provide the formatter with the `tz` parameter. For example, if you find the time zone of `dfweek2$Time` is "EST", then:

   `scale_x_datetime(labels = function(x) format(x, "%H:%M", tz = "EST"))`

Comment: thanks Nick. Both are insightful solutions. I also found that I had not set `tz` parameter, so it was taking local tz and and the `date_format` was taking `GMT` as default. Hence, the issue.